# Mock IHttpConnectionFeature in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, httpcontext

Hi I would like to mock IHttpConnectionFeature in ASP.NET Core

In my controller I have:

```
var connectionId = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>().ConnectionId;
```

but how can I mock it in my unit test:

```
        var controller = new MyController(logger.Object,
            mockService.Object)
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
            {
                HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
            }
        };
```

I'm getting an error message:

> Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 5):

You can add it like:

```
controller.HttpContext.Features.Set<IHttpConnectionFeature>(new HttpConnectionFeature()
{
     ConnectionId = "test"
});
```

Comment: You can also mock IHttpConnectionFeature instead of a real object

Comment: Exactly as @arni said: It is an interface, so do not create instances in unit test. Mock it.